# AWS SDK ToolKitfor Eclipse: EC2 instance is not showing

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I installed `AWS SDK ToolKit` for Eclipse. And I started and created a instance as described in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPFoDnjR8e8) video. But, I can't see this instance in Eclipse `AWS Explorer View` inside EC2 instances! What is wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that you launched the instance in a different region than what you are looking in the AWS Explorer View. If you change to different regions are you able to see it?

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko: You are correct. Please provide the comment as an answer